# How to return regex matched value from perl using batch?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I'm executing a perl regex command using batch like:

```
perl -p -e "<my regex>" c:\file.txt
PAUSE
```

How can I tell perl to return it as a veriable and then print the result using batch echo?

Comment: The perl script will print to STDOUT already, you do not need to print it with echo.

Comment: Of course I do not only want to print it out, I also want to use the found value in further batching. So I need to get it from perl.

Comment: @membersound, it helps if you say what you are really doing in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%q in ('perl -e"print q{a b c}"') do set var=%%q
echo %var%
pause
```

or

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%q in (`perl -e"print 'a b c'"`) do set var=%%q
echo %var%
pause
```

Comment: OK this would print "a b c", but still how get I return values from a regex match that looked the expression up in the file?