# Get return params from Perl one-liner regular expression

Tags: regex, windows, perl, batch-file

How can I return the matched value from a regular expression Perl execution?

I want to further use the match in my batch file.

Batch file:

```
perl -p -e "ab{2}" c:\file.txt
REM echo %var% how can I get the result from perl?
REM do something with %var%
```

File `file.txt`:

```
abbreviation
```

---

Update for zb226:

```
test

Filename: dynamicFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: the message I want
Time: dynamicTime
```

Comment: That one-liner won't return anything except the file content, which is printed to stdout. If you had warnings turned on, it would also print `Can't call method "ab" without a package or object reference at -e line 1.` to stderr.

Comment: I don't see any regex there oO !?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question and accept an answer?

Comment: @ikegami's solution looked good to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14981497/1919238

Comment: @TLP Similar, but I asked about printout/stdout which I now try to extend.

Comment: @membersound, the solution I linked to sets the return value into a variable, so you should be able to use it further.  Did you try that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `FOR` command for that:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('perl -ne "print $1.\"\n\" if ~/(ab{2})/" c:\file.txt') DO SET match=%%I
ECHO match: %match%
```

Note that this will return the last match - which does not matter with your example regexp `ab{2}`, as that will always return `abb` or nothing.

**Edit 1**: Forgot to add a newline in the perl onliner - alternatively you can use Andrey's `perl -pe ...` version, which does not require printing the newline.

**Edit 2**: Then again, Andrey's one-liner matches the regexp only at the beginning of a line, which is not what your question suggests. Also it prints non-matching lines, as you already noticed. I can't think of an easy fix for the `perl -pe` version...

**Edit 3**: Here's a quick and dirty solution for the additional information you've provided in the comment.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (`perl -e "local $/ = undef; open my $h, '<', $ARGV[0]; my $x = <$h>; print $1 if $x=~/Filename: dynamicFile.txt.*?Message: (.*?)Time/s;" c:\file.txt`) DO SET match=%%I
ECHO match: %match%
```

With a test file of...

```
test

Filename: dynamicFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: the message I want
Time: dynamicTime
----
Filename: someOtherFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: someMessage
Time: dynamicTime
```

...this outputs:

```
match: the message I want
```

Comment: Great, in my example it really works. Though I have problems porting it to my case. Maybe you could help one more? `(Filename: dynamicFile.txt.*?Message: \K.*?(?=\sTime))` is the expression I want to evaluate. The file content is: `Filename: dynamicFile.txt
Property: some property to neglect
Message: the message I want
Time: dynamicTime`. I tried it using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2tr28, but when I use the pattern in your perl oneliner, %match% is just empty. Why?

Comment: This is because your match spans multiple lines, which will need a different (and more complex) approach.

Comment: Oh no, I just discovered that if the "Filename" string comes right after an empty line, then the match is empty. I updated my answer with the filecontent example which does not work. Maybe you know what might be wrong. Which is strange because using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it works anyway. But using my local perl v5.16.2 it does not match anything.

Comment: Uh, that was an error on my part, the `local $/ = ''` needs to be `local $/ = undef` - then it works! Corrected answer...

Answer (score 0):

`perl -p -e "s/^(ab{2}).*$/\1/" c:\file.txt`

Comment: That would just print the whole file content. But what i'm looking for is just the matched to be returned.

Comment: this print abb only, what you match?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne "print $1 if /(ab{2})/" C:\file.txt
```